# switch statement in a reducer function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement, reduce

I've been at a lost with this problem for over 2 hours. I've tried so many things.

Here is the question:

- Write a switch statement for the provided reducer function such that
  when it is used to reduce the provided array of actions, it correctly
  produces a new state with the actions applied to it.
- Examine the code below, then delete the line indicated inside the
  definition of the reducer function. In its place, write a switch
  statement with a case for the 'update_hp' and 'update_pos' action
  types, as well as a default case.
  Your goal is to have the state variable, when logged at the end, contain
  an object with the content of: { hp: 800, xPosition: 205, yPosition: 190 }

This is the expected output:
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o94Ne.png)

I'm expected to update the reducer function.

Here is the code that I have so far:

````
const actions = [
    { type: 'update_hp', payload: -200 },
    { type: 'update_pos', payload: { x: 5, y: -10 } }
];

const initialState = {
    hp: 1000,
    xPosition: 200,
    yPosition: 200
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'update_hp':
            return {
                ...state,
                initialState.hp + actions.payload;        
            }
        case 'update_pos':
            return {
                ...state,
                initialState.xPosition + actions.payload.x
            }
        default:
            return {
                ...state,
                initialState.yPosition + actions.payload.y
            }
    return state;
};

const state = actions.reduce(reducer, initialState);
console.log(state); ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Lines like `initialState.hp + actions.payload;`  does not set the value after modifying it. So you need to update the value of the key, by getting the previous value from the state and adding new value to it

```
const actions = [{
    type: 'update_hp',
    payload: -200
  },
  {
    type: 'update_pos',
    payload: {
      x: 5,
      y: -10
    }
  }
];

const initialState = {
  hp: 1000,
  xPosition: 200,
  yPosition: 200
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'update_hp':
        return {
          ...state,
          hp: state.hp + actions.payload;
        }
      case 'update_pos':
        return {
          ...state,
          xPosition: state.xPosition + actions.payload.x
        }
      default:
        return {
          ...state,
          yPosition: state.state + actions.payload.y
        }
        return state;
    };

    const state = actions.reduce(reducer, initialState);
    console.log(state);
```